# Source in file for case statement

Tags: linux, bash, case

I have a simple code that runs a case statement that will grow over time.  I want other users to update the possible cases but I don't want them to update the code.  Is it possible to source in the options from a file called optionsfile.txt?

Current sample:

```
read input
case $input in
option1 )
  echo option1 ;;
option2 )
  echo option2 ;;
esac
```

Changed to:

```
read input
case $input in
Source in file here optionsfile.txt
esac
```

So the contents of the optionsfile.txt will look like this:

```
option1 )
  echo option1 ;;
option2 )
  echo option2 ;;
```

Comment: You can source the file given an option with just `. file`, but note that sourcing from somewhere else gives them complete control of your script.

Comment: `source` is not a macro expander; it executes valid shell code. A pair of naked cases is not valid shell code.

Comment: trying to source in the file doesn't work: options1
code: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `./optionsfile.txt'
code: line 3: `. ./optionsfile.txt'

Comment: @chepner Misread, thought they wanted to run code based on the options to case.

Comment: @tazmarine Thought you wanted to source actions of each option, as explained by chepner, you can't source incomplete code.

Comment: @tazmarine, if you're considering letting the users edit a file sourced by the main script, they might as well put any code in there, including ending the `case` or using command substitutions, so it doesn't protect the main script itself by much. If you have some simple-ish action you're doing for every option, it might be preferable to implement that and just load the keywords and values from the user-editable file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up using a script that gets called if the date time stamp is updated on the optionsfile.txt that makes a function. That function is sourced into the main code.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<Part1
userstuff() {
read input
case $input in
Part1
cat ./optionsfile.txt
cat <<Part2
esac
}
Part2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use 2 bash files:

**src.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Input: "
read input
./optionsfile.sh input
```

**optionsfile.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
case ${1} in
    "a")
        echo "You gave me a"
        ;;
    "b")
        echo "I hate b"
        ;;
esac
```

But please don't use this file structure and don't call `optionsfile.sh` that way :) It was my little test.

Comment: That doesn't source anything, though. It runs `optionsfile` in a subshell.

Comment: Just realized that.

Comment: @jiveturkey This may be an option but it leaves the case and esac and that is what I was trying to avoid.  The users that update will copy the first option and paste to the end and make adjustments.  This leaves the case and esac availble to be copied.

Comment: The `optionsfile.txt` file you provided will ideally do the same thing, correct?  There they can move options around and make adjustments as well.

Comment: That is correct.  It's pulling the optionsfile.txt into the case that I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that bash/shell might be the wrong medium for what you're trying to do, especially if you don't want your users to touch the code. Bash is too easily breakable. Sourcing anything in a bash script is necessarily letting them touch the code.

My second thought is to abstract your options into another format (ini, yaml, json, etc), and then beefing up your main script to parse the options with a 3rd party utility, like `crudini` or `jq`.

Or even use something more accessible (like PHP) for the whole thing. It's way more forgiving.

All that being said, if you are going to just `source` a 2nd file, I would recommend doing two things:

- don't lie and put a .txt extension on it, and
- put a shebang in it.

That way you're not tricking your users about what's going on. Your users, and the editors they use, will have a much better chance of not breaking everything.

Comment: Great advice.  I will explore some other options.  The current bash script itself is several hundred lines and has multiple cases already.  I was attempting to make it easier and a repeatable process for updating just that one case statement.

Answer (score 0):

## Consider two `case` statements

FWIW, consider that you can run two case statements. That could be helpful depending on your project.

**mainscript.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read input
case $input in
option1 )
  echo option1 ;;
option2 )
  echo option2 ;;
esac

. growingcases.sh
```

**growingcases.sh**

```bash
case $input in
option3 )
  echo option3 ;;
option4 )
  echo option4 ;;
esac
```

That was the answer to my situation, anyhow.